# Rewrite function with functools.reduce

Tags: python, python-3.x

This functions gets list of dictionaries and checks, if there are 5 records with the same year in a row.

```
def is_poorly_mixed_reduce(partition):
    cnt = 0
    prev_year = None
    for d in partition:
        curr_year = d["date"][:4]
        if curr_year == prev_year:
            cnt += 1
            if cnt == 5:
                return True
        else:
            cnt = 1
            prev_year = curr_year
        
    return False
```

How can i rewrite my function, using functools.reduce?

Example of partition data:

```
[
  {'user_id': 452355, 'recipe_id': 292657, 'date': '2016-05-08'},
  {'user_id': 3213, 'recipe_id': 21321, 'date': '2015-05-08'},
  {'user_id': 32145, 'recipe_id': 321, 'date': '2013-12-10'},
  {'user_id': 54366, 'recipe_id': 98745, 'date': '2012-12-10'},
  {'user_id': 23483, 'recipe_id': 498298, 'date': '2010-11-01'}
]
```

Comment: very difficult to say without seeing (something that is representative of) your data

Comment: you won't be able to break early, so you'll have to look at all the data. why do you want to use reduce?

Comment: updated question with example of data

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga just such kind of task and i haven't got any ideas how to realize it

Comment: you haven't even provided example inputs. Please don't be lazy.

Comment: added example of partition data, provided by the list of dictionaries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a good place to use `functools.reduce`, but you can do something to the effect of:

```py
def is_poorly_mixed(partitions):
    return functools.reduce(
        lambda acc, d: (
            (curr_year := d["date"][:4]), 
            (count:= acc[1] + 1 if curr_year == acc[0] else 1), 
            (acc[2] or count == 5)
        ),
        partitions,
        (None, 0, False)
    )[2]
```

It might be made more clear if you use a full function definition statement and some other object instead of a tuple/sequence for an accumulator. But again, you cannot break early with this, so you always consume the whole iterable. e.g.

```py
@dataclasses
class Accumulator:
    result: bool = False
    previous_year: typing.Optional[str] = None
    count: int = 0

def worker(acc: Accumulator, d: dict) -> Accumulator:
    current_year = d["date"][:4]
    count = acc.count + 1 if current_year == acc.previous_year else 1
    return Accumulator(
        result=acc.result or count == 5,
        count=count,
        previous_year=current_year,
    )

def is_poorly_mixed(partitions):
    return functools.reduce(woker, partitions, Accumulator()).result
```

Of course, you don't really want to do that. If you really want to use the standard library here, use `itertools.groupby`, something to the effect of:

```
import itertools
def is_poorly_mixed(partitions):
    grouped = itertools.groupby(lambda d: d["date"][:4], partitions)
    for _, group in grouped:
        count = sum(1 for _ in group)
        if count == 5:
            return False
    return True
```